# How does one use pandas.merge in order to merge two dataframes, so that one is added multiple times to the next?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I am currently working on a Movie Recommender system as a project. In order to do so, I had created two datasets- (pics included)
df3, which has a user ID, movie ID, and the rating given to the movie.
df, which contains the movie ID, and details about the movie(cast,budget,runtime, etc).
I want to make a function that takes the two datasets and 'expands' df3 in a way that for each movie ID in df3, the function then 'adds' the movie details from df, of the same movie. which means the amount of rows in the final dataset will be the same as there are rows in df3, but with more columns(columns also coming from df).
I had tried doing so many different ways, using all 3 pandas functions for combining dataframes and creating  a function of my own, to no avail.

Would anyone be kind enough to help me sort this mess out? I've asked teachers, friends, seen tutorials, scoured every youtube video, guide & looked at previously asked questions, yet nothing works.

[df3

[image: 1]

[df]

[image: 2]

Tries of mine include:

- `test = df3.join(other = df,how='left',on='id')`
- `df3 = df3.merge(right=df, how='left',suffixes=None)`
- `df_movies = pd.merge(left=df3, right = df, left_on='id', right_on='id', how='right')`
- `df3.merge(df,how='right')`

among others.

Comment: Try with `how='inner'` (assuming there is an entry in `df` for every movie appearing in `df3`) with `merge`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I've tried using merge with inner. Yes, there should be an entry in df for every entry in df3 (but more entries in df3- some movies were rated by more than 1 person). But for some reason when I use inner the amount of rows gets slashed and reduced to around 85000 from the beginning with 100000.

Comment: You should try to find a few rows of `df3` which vanished e. g. by converting the `id` columns to sets and doing a set difference.

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of your input data? From that sample, what would be expected output?